# New to Grafana, which graph/plugin for this type of diagram?

Tags: grafana

Let’s suppose, I have a table like this
(*I should be able to modify the structure of the table if I want)

```
Title                q_point             a_point
element_1,          4                       5
element_2,          1                       2
element_3,          2                       4
element_4,          2                       4
element_5,          1                       2
```

I’d like to generate something similar to what I’ve below with Grafana, I’ve been looking around but I did not find anything that exactly fit what I've to do.

[image]

Is there any plugin/graph which allows me to build something similar, possibly including colors…

Thanks a lot

Comment: I would say only your own custom plugin. In theory you can use table panel, but then SQL will be very complex and it won't provide cell colloring.

Comment: I've 20 days to put something together so unfortunately writing a plugin is excluded, at least within this timeline... what were you thinking about table panel and SQL, all that I can think of would not really work...

Comment: Example for "row1": `SELECT  
   '5' AS "q_point",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN a_point == 1 THEN 1 END) AS a1,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN a_point == 2 THEN 1 END) AS a2,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN a_point == 3 THEN 1 END) AS a3,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN a_point == 4 THEN 1 END) AS a4,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN a_point == 5 THEN 1 END) AS a5
FROM <table>` - you will write query for each row + `UNION` the results and you have table (I guess some adjustements will be needed, e.g, zero hiding, labeling, ...) - you have full SQL available.

Comment: @JanGaraj thanks!!I'll try it out

Comment: @JanGaraj, as anticipated by you the only problem with this approach is the color, there is no way i can achieve the coloring of the cells using the SQL table, i can define colors just based on values and the values will keep changing so they can't be used as reference... If you have any other idea feel free to shout it out :)